# Dialogue from a distance?

Tags: dialogue

There’s a Quadbike going down a hill, the two people on the quad are talking, but you can’t see their mouths move.
You know it’s them talking as you saw them talk before and know their voices... 
my question is:
Do I use (V.O.) or (O.S) ?

Comment: You have basically copied your older question. Why do you think answers in this case would be different? The goal of StackExchange is to have one question with all the possible answers ranked by their merit, which is why we are closing duplicates and pointing people to the canonical question. If you think it should be reopened please [edit] it to show what's different. If answers are currently not satisfactory you should place a bounty on the question, which you can do at 75 reputation. If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: It also looks like you accidentally have an unregistered account for your old question (which is why you can't simply edit it and would have to suggest and edit). You might be interested in the meta question [How can one link / merge / combine / associate two accounts / users? (Anonymous / unregistered / cookie, or OpenID / registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18232/352819) to combine those accounts and collect the reputation from your older question as well as being able to simply comment everywhere under your own questions or edit them.